# Getting full url in express app running as firebase function -- including the function name?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

This seems a bit more challenging than just generally getting the url + path due to express being served from a secondary path.

I'm trying to dynamically create redirect/callback URL's for passport based OpenID integrations.

So far, I've successfully gotten as much using the req.host as directed in other stackoverflow threads:

```
callbackURL: "https://" + req.get("host") + "/auth/apple/redirect",
```

I do not need protocol as I'm only dealing with https all the time.

The issue is, my function is being served from:

```
https://europe-west2-projectname.cloudfunctions.net/MY_FUNCTION_NAME/
```

and therefore using just host, the url above will not be a valid redirect URL that Oauth can use.

I am doing this as I have 1 single app running off of 2 different functions depending if i'm in staging OR production.

To further add insult to injury -- firebase functions within the same app seem to share their environmental variables so I can't really count on those either.

Comment: Which part of this specifically are you having problems with?  An HTTP function simply knowing its own name?  Can you find anything helpful in the express path at all? https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.path

Comment: BTW the recommended advice for handling environments like staging and prod in Firebase/Google Cloud is to use different projects.  Doing it this way will save you a lot of trouble in the future, even if it seems harder at first.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_different_environments

Comment: Thanks, sadly req.path only shows "/" -- I guess essentially just the function name would be sufficient to construct the right URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Google Cloud documentation:

- [node 6 and 8](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_6_nodejs_8_python_37_and_go_111) offer FUNCTION_NAME as an environment variable that indicates which function is being run.
- [node 10](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_10_and_subsequent_runtimes) offers FUNCTION_TARGET.

Comment: hah, I literally went to add the FUNCTION_NAME env. variable in GCP's cloud functions console manually. Oh well, live and learn, thanks!